# Comparar uma coluna bit nula

Tags: sql-server

Sei que o resultado das consultas abaixo são os mesmo, mas gostaria de saber se existe diferença na execução pelo SqlServer em questões de performance e etc.

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTES C WHERE C.FL_EXCLUIDO IS NULL OR C.FL_EXCLUIDO = 0
```

ou

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTES C WHERE ISNULL(C.FL_EXCLUIDO, 0) = 0
```

Comment: Quantas linhas, aproximadamente, tem a tabela CLIENTES? // Qual  percentagem de FL_EXCLUIDO 'false' ou NULL sobre o total?

Answer (score 1):

Eu já havia visto algumas coisas sobre isso, tem até um post bem interessante no SO inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118213/isnull-vs-is-null

Mas no exemplo do link, está comparando um campo texto, e no seu caso é um campo bit.

Então resolvi fazer um teste com uma tabela aqui. Habilitando o Exec Plan, executei uma query semelhante à sua, usando um campo `bit` `null`, e, em dois testes, um com uma tabela com algumas centenas de registros e outra com alguns milhares de registros, o resultado foi o mesmo: `IS NULL` requeria a criação de um índice para as tabelas. Já a função `ISNULL` executou sem solicitar um índice.

Quanto ao tempo de execução, na tabela com cerca de 50mil registros não houve diferença relevante, assim como em uma tabela com alguns milhões de registros, que foi a seguinte:

`IS NULL`: 01:21 (1m2s)
`ISNULL()`: 01:19 (1m19s)

Aqui o resultado do Exec Plan para analisarem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso pode induzir à conclusão de que `IS NULL` executaria teoricamente mais rápido, já que sugeriu a criação de um índice, mas isso pode não ser verdade.
Para concluir, resolvi criar o índice e testar novamente os tempos de execução, que foram:

`IS NULL`: 00:08 (8s)
`ISNULL()`: 00:03 (3s)

Com isso podemos ver que, no caso de um campo `bit` nullable, `ISNULL` teve a mesma performance sem índice, e com índice foi muito superior, levou 37,5% do tempo do `IS NULL`, ou seja, menos da metade, muito mais rápido.
Claro que outros cenários e uma cláusula `WHERE` diferente, podem trazer resultados diferentes, sendo sempre recomendando analisar o Exec Plain para determinar a melhor query.

Answer (score 0):

Rafael, há vários fatores que determinam a performance de uma construção SELECT, inclusive se há índices e, neste caso, quais as características dos índices existentes.

De imediato, algumas observações sobre as duas construções que publicou neste tópico, que, para facilitar os comentários, referenciei como

**(a)** SELECT * FROM CLIENTES C WHERE C.FL_EXCLUIDO IS NULL OR C.FL_EXCLUIDO = 0;

**(b)** SELECT * FROM CLIENTES C WHERE ISNULL(C.FL_EXCLUIDO, 0) = 0;

---

**(1)** Na construção (a), a cláusula WHERE contém o operador lógico OR. Geralmente, restrições do tipo

```
WHERE expressão_lógica1 OR expressão_lógica2 OR ...
```

podem forçar (ou não) uma leitura sequencial, seja através de índice (*index scan*) ou diretamente na tabela (*table scan*). Sugiro que analise o plano de execução para verificar o que o *query optimizer* escolheu. Dicas no artigo “[O Plano Perfeito](https://portosql.wordpress.com/blog/)”.

---

**(2)** Na construção (b) a cláusula WHERE contém chamada de função tendo como parâmetro coluna da tabela. Isto geralmente impede que o SQL Server encontre o índice adequado (caso exista), pois a restrição torna-se *non sargable*, ocorrendo também a leitura sequencial, seja através de índice (*index scan*) ou diretamente na tabela (*table scan*). Novamente sugiro que analise o plano de execução. Detalhes no artigo “[Construindo códigos T-SQL eficientes: Sargability](https://portosql.wordpress.com/artigos/)”.

---

**(3)** Outro fator que pode influenciar na performance é o que contém a *lista_de_colunas* da cláusula SELECT. Construções do tipo

```
SELECT *
```

podem inviabilizar a escolha de índice *nonclustered*, principalmente se não for de cobertura. Isto envolve inclusive a presença ou não do operador [Pesquisa de chave](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb326635.aspx) (*Key lookup*) no plano de execução.

---

**(4)** Supondo que o objetivo da consulta seja o de obter somente a identificação do cliente, poderíamos ter então

```
(c)
SELECT idCliente FROM CLIENTES C WHERE C.FL_EXCLUIDO IS NULL OR C.FL_EXCLUIDO = 'false';
```

mas ainda assim ocorreria leitura sequencial (*scan*), por causa do exposto em (1). Exceto se houver índice pela coluna `FL_EXCLUIDO` e que contenha a coluna `idCliente`:

```
CREATE nonclustered INDEX I2_CLIENTES on CLIENTES(FL_EXCLUIDO) include (idCliente);
```

A construção

```
(d)
SELECT idCliente FROM CLIENTES C WHERE C.FL_EXCLUIDO IS NULL     
union all      
SELECT idCliente FROM CLIENTES C WHERE C.FL_EXCLUIDO = 'false';
```

pode ser eficiente caso existam os seguintes índices filtrados:

```
CREATE nonclustered INDEX I3_CLIENTES on CLIENTES(FL_EXCLUIDO) include (idCliente) where FL_EXCLUIDO = 'false';     
CREATE nonclustered INDEX I4_CLIENTES on CLIENTES(FL_EXCLUIDO) include (idCliente) where FL_EXCLUIDO is null;
```

É claro que também depende do volume de dados.

---

**(5)** Poderia enumerar aqui vários outros fatores. Entretanto, a construção  (b), por ser *non sargable*, ocorrerá leitura sequencial (*scan*). Exceto se utilizada a técnica de forçar o predicado para sargable, conforme descrito no artigo “[Construindo códigos T-SQL eficientes: Sargability](https://portosql.wordpress.com/artigos/)”, item 4.2.

---

**(6)** Os valores válidos para a coluna FL_EXCLUIDO são 'true' e 'false', além da ausência de informação (NULL). Ou seja, a construção (a) poderia ser reescrita como

```
(e)
SELECT * from CLIENTES
except
SELECT * from CLIENTES where FL_EXCLUIDO = 'true';
```

A eficiência (ou não) dessa solução depende das características da coluna FL_EXCLUIDO e dos índices existentes.